# $p$ is irreducible and $p\mid bc$ follow that $p\mid b$ or $p\mid c$

Tags: field-theory

[image]
[image]

[image]

Any explanation why $d$ must be a **monic** polynomial? ($p,b,c$ are not monic). Thanks.

Comment: As the text say: "by definition".  The definition of GCD begins with: "It's the monic polynomial such that ..."

Comment: If you are using $GCD(...)$ as expression for an element, a single one must be chosen. By multiplication by an invertible element we can make any nonzero polynomial monic, and since the definition cannot exclude such multiplications, it is convenient for the definition to choose the monic polynbomial.

Comment: I just want to point out that if $F$ is a field, then $F[x]$ is a PID (in fact, the converse also holds) - and in any PID, primes and irreducibles coincide, i.e., $x$ is prime iff $x$ is irreducible. In general, however, only one direction is true, i.e., $x$ is prime implies $x$ is irreducible. If you can prove these more general results, you can completely avoid the proof in the image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In any commutative ring $R$, two elements $r_1, r_2 \in R$ may have more than one greatest common divisor.

For example:

- If $R = \mathbb Z$, $r_1 = 4$, $r_2 = 6$, then $2$ is a greatest common divisor of $r_1$ and $r_2$, but so is $-2$.
- If $R = \mathbb Q[x]$, $r_1 = (x-1)(x-2)$ and $r_2 = (x-2)^3(x-7)$, then $(x-2)$ is a greatest common divisor of $r_1$ and $r_2$, but so is $12345(x-2)$.

In general if $d$ is a greatest common divisor of $r_1, r_2$, then so is $du$, where $u$ is any unit in $R$.

In $F[x]$, the units are the non-zero elements of $F$. If $d$ is a greatest common divisor of $f, g \in F[x]$, then we can construct another greatest common divisor of $f, g \in F[x]$ that is a monic polynomial. Indeed, if $c \in F^\times$ is the leading coefficient of $d$, then $c$ is a unit in $F[x]$, so $d' := c^{-1}d$ is another greatest common divisor of $f$ and $g$ that also happens to be a monic polynomial

Presumably your textbook adopts the following convention: Whenever your textbook talks about "the" greatest common divisor of $f, g \in F[x]$, it is really referring the (unique) *monic* greatest common divisor $f, g \in F[x]$.

Whether $f$ and $g$ are themselves monic is irrelevant.